# PHP error handler and ErrorException confusion: log stack trace

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I want to log all PHP errors to a database, all with a stack trace. But the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) snippet has me confused:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

I currently use the function that I pass to `set_error_handler()' to log the error to the database. But if I use the above code, **where do I put the code that writes the error and stack trace to the database?**

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $err = array(
        'errno' => $errno,
        'errstr' => $errstr,
        'errfile' => $errfile,
        'errline' => $errline
    );
    DB::insertAssoc('table_error', $err);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with Exceptions, you need to use `try {/* code */} catch (Exception $error) {/* handle exception code*/}`. Try this:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $err = array(
            'errno' => $errno,
            'errstr' => $errstr,
            'errfile' => $errfile,
            'errline' => $errline
    );

    DB::insertAssoc('table_error', $err);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    $q/1;
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    error_handler(
        $e->getSeverity(),
        $e->getMessage(),
        $e->getFile(),
        $e->getLine()
    );
}
```

You can read more about working with exceptions in Php here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks - Is there a way to globally catch exceptions, without having a try/catch block surrounding all the code on a page?

Comment: You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php , but script execution will be stopped after call to it. It's better to properly work with exceptions if you use them